# Проблемы с запросами php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

Перерыл весь рунет и инет ничего не нашел толком. Может здесь помогут мне. Суть не работает последний запрос. Он не выполняется.

```
<?
session_start();
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/conf/db_connect.php';

$sql = "call get_user_by_user_name('$_POST[username]')";
$get_user = db_query($sql, $link, $_SESSION[mode]);
$row = db_fetch($get_user, $_SESSION[mode]);

if(!empty($row[user_id]))
{
    header ("location:/reg/regindex.php?error=1");
    exit;
}

if( !empty( $_FILES['avatar']['name'] ) )
{
    $userAvatar = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/avatars/' .$_POST['username']. basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
    $userAvatarPath = '/avatars/' .$_POST['username']. basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
    if( substr($_FILES['avatar']['type'], 0, 5)=='image' )
    {
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $userAvatar))
        {
            header ("location:/reg/regindex.php?error=2");
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header ("location:/reg/regindex.php?error=2");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    unset($userAvatar);
    unset($userAvatarPath);
}
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$userPassword = $_POST['pw'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$userFirstName = $_POST['firstname'];
$userLastName = $_POST['lastname'];
$birthdate = $_POST['date'];


$userName = stripslashes($userName);
$userName = htmlspecialchars($userName);
$userName = addslashes($userName);

$userPassword = stripslashes($userPassword);
$userPassword = htmlspecialchars($userPassword);
$userPassword = addslashes($userPassword);

$userFirstName = stripslashes($userFirstName);
$userFirstName = htmlspecialchars($userFirstName);
$userFirstName = addslashes($userFirstName);

$userLastName = stripslashes($userLastName);
$userLastName = htmlspecialchars($userLastName);
$userLastName = addslashes($userLastName);

$email = stripslashes($email);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$email = addslashes($email);

$userName = trim($userName);
$userPassword = trim($userPassword);
$userFirstName = trim($userFirstName);
$userLastName = trim($userLastName);
$email = trim($email);

$userName = str_replace("'","’",$userName);
$userPassword = str_replace("'","’",$userPassword);
$userFirstName = str_replace("'","’",$userFirstName);
$userLastName = str_replace("'","’",$userLastName);
$email = str_replace("'","’",$email);

$sql_two = "call add_user('$userName','$userPassword','$email','$userLastName','$userLastName','$birthdate','$userAvatarPath')";
db_query($sql_two, $link, $_SESSION['mode']);

header ("location:/reg/regend.php");
?>
```

Если я закоментирую это

```
$sql = "call get_user_by_user_name('$_POST[username]')";
    $get_user = db_query($sql, $link, $_SESSION[mode]);
    $row = db_fetch($get_user, $_SESSION[mode]);
```

Все работает. Иначе наоборот. Даже ошбок не выдает, если "or die" уберу.  Ни с одним не работает. $link - глобальная переменная подключения, делал проверки перед последним запросом, подключение не отваливается. С ним вроде проблем нет. Есть еще один файл, там идут два подряд запроса

```
$tempRow = db_row(db_query("SELECT count(*) FROM view_guest_book", $link, $_SESSION['mode']), $_SESSION['mode']);
$result = db_query("call get_entries_gb_per_page('$per_page', '$start')", $link, $_SESSION['mode']);
```

Функция db_query.

```
function db_query($query, $link, $conntype)
{

    switch($conntype)
    {
        case "sqlb":
        {
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("\nНекорректный SQL запрос >>" . $query);
            return $result;
            break;
        }
        case "sqlip":
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("\nНекорректный SQL запрос >>" . $query);
            return $result;
            break;
        }
        case "sqlio":
        {
            $result = $link->query($query) or die("\nНекорректный SQL запрос >>" . $query);
            return $result;
            break;
        }
        case "pdo":
        {
            $result = $link->prepare($query);
            $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            $result->execute() or die("\nНекорректный SQL запрос >>" . $query);
            return $result;
            break;
        }
        default:break;

    }
}
```

db_row примерно такая же, только там используются функции соответствующие расширениям. Да и еще такой момент, до этого другую базу данных, и запросы были напрямую к таблицам, не через процедуры и работало. В общем мозги кипят вообще бред какой-то.

Comment: Не дописал про те два подряд запроса. В том порядке что я написал они работают, если поменять местами, то точно такая же бурда. Работало когда стояли SELECT'ы, сейчас с процедурами нихрена.

Comment: вы бы объеденили бы эти  stripslashes, trim, htmlspecialchars , и потом вы сначала убираете экранирование символов stripslashes а потом добавляете , порядком ошиблись вы

Comment: Я это делал, когда не знал, что еще может мне помочь. От отчаяния, сейчас проблему нашел, нужно код в порядок привести.

Comment: include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/conf/db_connect.php';  а здесь точно  правильно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблему я нашел, если вызывать хранимки в коде, то, после них в коде ни один запрос не сработает. Как теперь только от этого недуга избавится.
Опишу проблему.
Если запросы стоят в таком порядке

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "call get_entries_gb_per_page('$per_page', '$start')");
$result_2= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) FROM view_guest_book");
```

То второй запрос после вызова хранимки не сработает. Я не знаю с чем это связано. Если же их местами поменять, то сработает. Очевидно, что проблема в вызове хранимки, потому что до этого в коде я их не использовал, а тут необходимость появилась. Да и уже не первый раз я встречаю эту проблему, пока с хранимками работаю.

UPDATE
Проблема решена. Правда я не знаю с чем это связано, может объяснит кто. В общем непосредственно перед выполнением запроса вставляю строчку

```
if(mysqli_next_result($link)) mysqli_store_result($link);
```

Выглядит примерно так:

```
if(mysqli_next_result($link)) mysqli_store_result($link);
$result = mysqli_query($link, "call get_entries_gb_per_page('$per_page', '$start')");
if(mysqli_next_result($link)) mysqli_store_result($link);
$result_2= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) FROM view_guest_book");
```

Comment: дабавьте пример что бы не быть пустословом и автор проверит и выберет ваш вариант лучшим

Comment: Кто-нибудь сможет объяснить почему так происходит?

Comment: @LenovoID а кто автор?

Comment: автор Илья , но я написал свой комментарий  но не прочитал имя того дал ответ